# What is the term for a founding member of a group that gives its name to the rest of the group?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, nouns, terminology

I'm struggling to recollect a word, and I can't manage a Google search which has helped me!

I am trying to remember the term for a "founding member". For example, what is amborella in reference to Amborellaceae or rose to Rosids, or magnolia to Magnoliids.

I'm sure there are examples outside of flowers too!

Thanks!

Comment: Forerunner? Namesake?

Comment: 'Eponym' is given at the linked thread. Lord Sandwich ...> the sandwich. General Ambrose Burnside ...> sideburns. Narcissus. Gregorian chants. There's also 'protonym'.

Comment: Thank you both!